# Room Persistance: error when field has type of nested class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I try to implemenent room with a kotlin data class, but get this error:

> Error: Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor
>   Error Code:

```
interface Bar {
    data class Foo(val value: String)
}

@Entity
data class Baz(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long,
    val foo: Bar.Foo
)
```

If carry `Foo` out of the interface it's ok.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: do you have a type converter for `Foo` for Room?

Comment: @HawkPriest Yes.

Comment: `object Converters { @TypeConverter @JvmStatic fun fromFoo(value: Bar.Foo?)...`

Comment: I have the same issue, still haven't been able to fix it. Did you figure out the solution?